# Why are comments restricted to a single paragraph

Tags: discussion, comments

As far as I can tell, comments seem to be restricted to a single paragraph.  They do not support new lines or other line breaks.

Whilst this may often be fine, sometimes it isn't appropriate and doesn't scan well.

Is there a reason for prohibiting line breaks, or am I just missing something here?

Comment: What do you want to put in the comments that needs to be longer? Comments aren't for answers.

Comment: By "single paragraph" do you mean not supporting line break/newlines?

Comment: Comments are generally given much less love than answers, very intentionally. The suppression of line breaks is part of it (along with the size limit, no pictures, and no nesting/replies)

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Correct!

Comment: Well, we didn't even have comments at the beginning *at all*.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Very droll, I like the cut of your jib!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are generally:

- used for asking for clarification on a specific part of a question
- used to point out inconsistencies or incorrect information in an answer
- short, pithy
- *very much* third-class citizens

Comments are generally not:

- meant to facilitate long discussions
- meant to be used as a forum or sounding board
- meant to encapsulate lots of information (code, text)

Of course, Meta is slightly different in this context.

If you find yourself writing very long comments often, rethink that; if you have a lot to say or you want to strike up a conversation about this, then take it to a chatroom instead.

Comment: Note to self. Do not ask naive questions in the future

Comment: It's not a naive question.  At least you had the courage to ask it as opposed to learning it the hard way.

Comment: The down votes appear to disagree with you!

Comment: @RolfofSaxony - The down votes are likely just disagreement with, "sometimes it isn't appropriate". Voting on Meta is often used to reflect agreement/disagreement with something in the post and doesn't necessarily mean you shouldn't have asked at all.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, be aware that voting on meta doesn't come at a cost to reputation, so they are generally used to show support or disagreement, rather than as a measure of quality.

Comment: BSMP & zzzzBov : Those points are good to know. I shall bear them in mind for the future, namely, that the rules for meta are slightly different.