# Why don't comments support the full markdown?

Tags: support, comments, formatting

If you read the formatting help for comments it reads:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting

Why isn't the full markdown (the one that can be used on answers/questions) used?

Comment: @Paulie_D that's an irrelevant question. The OP is asking according to others "find out why markdown is not usable in comments". This asks why only a subset of markdown is applicable in comments. I reckon that markdown is usable on comments, that question, according to popular interpretation doesn't.

Comment: It would be quite beneficial if you could point out exactly which features of full markdown you wish to use in comments because as it stands the answer is simply that comments don't need full markdown capabilities.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus this is a support post, not a feature request. In other words, I'm asking why a feature was designed the way it was, not that I want to change it.

Comment: So per my previous comment, "comments don't need full markdown capabilities" would be a sufficient answer then, right?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus no, you need to explain "**why** comments don't need full markdown capabilities". Remember, the sky is blue due rayleigh scattering, not because the color of the air is blue.

Comment: Why was the rayleigh scattering used over other methods of making the sky blue? Why did rayleigh scattering choose blue; why not hot pink? Why doesn't the sky support brown and blue at the same time? "comments don't need full markdown capabilities because the engineering team went through extensive discussions and decision making". You should [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) them and ask for the meeting minutes of those discussions.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think that was explained here https://xkcd.com/224/. BTW, [support] tag excerpt: A request for **assistance with one of the site's features**

Comment: That's quite a roundabout way of asking for documentation but whatever. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @MonkeyZeus *I* **know** what `markdown`, is [available](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) on comments, that doesn't explain why is that. I don't need assistance on using markdown, I need assistance on why that feature behave that way.

Comment: Bad dupe closure is bad.

Comment: @Braiam the questions are essentially duplicates.  I reopened both and then made this the duplicate target as the answers are better.

Comment: @YvetteColomb no, they are not. Please, read very carefully what issues each question brings up. The other question notes the **complete lack of markdown support on comments** (the very self answer by OP tells you so), this one deals with the **why isn't markdown fully implemented**, unlike posts.

Comment: @Braiam I understand your point of view. Please try to understand others. One asks "why doesn't markdown apply in comments" other "why isn't markdown fully supported". The answer to both is the same. It would be really good if you could take a moment and see that point of view.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I think I asked one of the question, right? Don't I get priority over what the answer I'm looking for? I'm the OP here! I know what I asked, *I* crafted the question. Since you want me to follow what others say, that also applies to *you*. Follow [BDL advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377171/should-a-question-be-marked-as-a-duplicate-where-the-question-is-different-but-o#comment650942_377171) and evaluate if your judgement fails or not that simple litmus test. Are all answers to this question and to that question the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I include new lines for code snippets inside comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254976/how-can-i-include-new-lines-for-code-snippets-inside-comments)

Answer (score 15):

It's easy enough to consider when you go through them individually.

1. You can only use inline hyperlinks, rather than footnoted hyperlinks, because you only have a single line.
2. You can't use block quotes because you only have a single line of text, no room for the block.
3. There isn't space for an embedded image.
4. You can't use a multi-line code block because there's only a single line.
5. You can't use numbered lists, or bulleted lists, because there's only a single line.
6. You can't use headers because there's on a single line of text.
7. You can't use a horizontal rule because there's only a single line of text.

So really you couldn't implement any of the markdown that isn't supported even if you tried to.  All of the markdown that can practically be implemented in a format that is a single paragraph is implemented.

Comment: 1 isn't even true for post markdown (the flavor SE uses doesn't allow footnote hyperlinks). 2, 4, 5, 6 and 7 begs the question "why is a single line of text". Also, you can paste paragraphs in comments, but newlines`

`are stripped away (unless you abuse the code markdown). This answer is too superficial in addressing why all of these decisions were made when designing the support of formatting for comments. (BTW, it's possible for an embedded image in comments, it would just look ugly and wonky)

Comment: @Braiam I'm referring to the syntax of having the link at the end of the markup, rather than immediately following the link text, not that the link itself is at the end of the post.  Like I said, an image wouldn't *fit*, given that the format of posts is a single paragraph.  Why comments have such a restrictive length limit is really a different question than what you asked.  You weren't asking why comments can't be lengthy and multiple paragraphs long

Comment: But why is "the format of posts is a single paragraph"? If you open yourself to the rabbit hole in a question asking the why, you should go *all the way*. Or you want me to ask yet another question to which the answer is still the same: because comments has a intended purpose, and for such purpose all the features of posts aren't needed.

Comment: @Braiam I think that's something adequately covered already in the help center and other meta posts, so while that is a different question than the one that you asked, I don't think it's a *useful* question to ask and would just merit downvotes.  If it weren't already well covered, *then* it would be a question worth asking.

Comment: "I think that's something adequately covered already in the help center and other meta posts" if it was, I assure you that I would know about it. Remember, I'm the most pedantic person you can find on meta, and I know that such design decision isn't explained anywhere

Comment: @Braiam I just did a single search and [this was the top result](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303984/why-are-comments-restricted-to-a-single-paragraph).  So apparently you didn't do much in the way of research.

Comment: Yet you didn't linked to it, nor even followed Makoto way of explaining it. "Comments are generally: used for asking for clarification on a specific part of a question; used to point out inconsistencies or incorrect information in an answer [...]" which I did. So, I did research, I didn't find why comments only support a restricted set of markdown, but I knew very well why other features weren't added.

Comment: @Braiam The answer explains why there is a restricted set of markdown provided.  You have a follow up question of why comments are designed to be short and single paragraph.  I didn't answer it in this question because that's not what you asked.  If you want to know the answer to that question, you only needed to search.

Comment: No. That's a leap logic. I went directly to the root cause: purpose of comments. You are only leading the reader into a rodeo. A critical thinker, wouldn't make that mistake.

Comment: @Braiam You're accusing me of leap logic because I answered the question of "why is there limited markup" by explaining why the markup is limited, instead of why comments are expected to be a single paragraph, while you didn't explain why markdown is limited at all, and instead answered the question of why comments are limited to a single paragraph, and you think *I'm* the one with "leap logic"?  If all you want is an answer to the question of why comments are a single paragraph, I linked you to an answer.  If you want to know why markdown is limited, see what I posted here.

Comment: Why markdown on comments is limited is properly answered (the same why of why comments are single paragraphs) with the purpose of comments, themselves.

Answer (score -8):

The purpose of comments, contrary to other kinds of posts (questions, answers, tag wiki) is transient and very specific. Its purpose is actually to improve the post themselves in the way of asking for clarifications or to point out issues with it.

For that specific purpose, you don't need too much formatting outside linking and giving emphasis. This reasoning also applies to tag excerpts.

TL;dr: comments don't need post feature, because their purpose is too different.

Comment: I would add that the limitation of comments being a single line inherently restricts the available markup anyway.

Comment: @deceze that limitation is due the stated purpose of comments "asking for clarifications or to point out issues". If you need paragraphs to do that, then the post itself shouldn't be addressed via comments but other moderation tools.

Comment: @Braiam: Do you really need a "TL;DR" for a post that's 3 paragraphs *including* the "TL;DR"?

Comment: the comment help does first and foremost link to the page explaining [what comments are for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). It does neglect to explain the reason for the limitations of a comment. It'd be better if that were fixed rather than having a detached meta answer, wouldn't it?

Comment: @NicolBolas apparently, given that even you close voted the question as duplicate of another unrelated post.

Comment: @Gimby it isn't immediately obvious that the purpose of something has anything to do with the reason. Likewise, people misunderstand the purpose of voting as a quality assessment of the post, not to be mean to the poster.